# Xcode Other Linker Flags -ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, amazon-web-services

I am fairly new to iOS development so please forgive me if this is a trivial question.

I am working on an iPhone application that uses the Google frameworks, more specifically,

```
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
```

I followed the instructions located at the following URL: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started.  Step 6 specifies to add the flag `-ObjC` to **Other Linker Flags**.  If I follow all the instructions on this page and the next page located here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in, I can successfully obtain an AUTH token from Google along with the correct email address from the Google+ account.

After completing this, I have added AWS frameworks to my project, more specifically,

```
#import <AWSRuntime/AWSRuntime.h>
#import <AWSRuntime/AmazonCredentials.h>
#import <AWSDynamoDB/AWSDynamoDB.h>
#import <AWSDynamoDB/DynamoDBGetItemRequest.h>
```

But when compile, I get the following compile time errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSStoreTypeKey", referenced from:
      -[AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore loadMetadata:] in AWSPersistence(AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore.o)
  "_NSStoreUUIDKey", referenced from:
      -[AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore loadMetadata:] in AWSPersistence(AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSPersistence(AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSPersistence(AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSIncrementalStore", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore in AWSPersistence(AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSIncrementalStoreNode", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSPersistence(AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSPersistence(AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSRelationshipDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSPersistence(AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSIncrementalStore", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore in AWSPersistence(AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now if I remove the `-ObjC` flag from **Other Linker Flags**, everything compiles, the AWS frameworks work but the Google+ button does nothing when clicking on it.

I feel I am missing something simple, like maybe using the -ObjC flag just on the Google frameworks but I cannot find anything on this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you need to add the Core Data framework.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you!  How did adding this framework fix these errors if you don't mind me asking.  FYI - If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Comment: It fixed the problem because the Core Data framework provides the missing symbols you reported.